# Magento SOAP: how to update quantity increments?

Tags: c#, web-services, magento, soap

I'm using SOAP v2 in a C# project, and I need to create many articles using [catalogProductCreate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html).

Now, the object [catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html) does not have the field **qty_increments**.
Even in the documentation there is no trace of it, while all other fields in the administration and in the database are present.

How can i update this value (for the single product)?
Does anybody have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I just discovered that using REST the field **qty_increments** does exist.

[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html)

Why it's not available in SOAP?
It's a bug or I'm wrong with something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution: creating a module that adds **qty_increments** and **qty_incrementsSpecified** in the object **catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity**.

In this way I have the two parameters set via SOAP while creating or updating products.

This is the main code in ***wsdl.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <complexType name="catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="use_config_qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>
```

and this is ***wsi.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
         targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <xsd:complexType name="catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xsd:element name="use_config_qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only with adding the following 4 elements to wsdl (***wsi.xml***):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
         targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="enable_qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="use_config_enable_qty_inc" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="use_config_qty_increments" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Without the elements **enable_qty_increments** and **use_config_enable_qty_inc** the answer of clkurtz didn't worked for me because the option **qty_increments** was still disabled. I think you need the this two elements only when you have **qty_increments** disabled in the standard configuration.